# Inserting elements into all XML tags

Tags: xml, notepad++, sublimetext3

I have lines of XML script like this...

```
<line id='1'>............</line>
```

I need to add more elements into the tags, basically into this:

```
<line id='1' anim="idle" exp="F00">.........</line>
```

Is there quick way to do that to all lines in the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<line id='\w+'`
- Replace with: `$0 anim="idle" exp="F00"`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<line id='  : literally "<line id='"
\w+         : 1 or more word character
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0                      : whole match, ie. the tag
 anim="idle" exp="F00"  : what you want to add with a space before
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<line id='1' anim="idle" exp="F00">............</line>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still need that id number. Hence I modified your syntax to `<line id='\w+'`